# Spring Scheduling

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a cron expression which will run everyday at 7 PM .
I am using spring boot latest version.

```
      @Scheduled(cron = "${my.cron.expression}")
        public void scheduleTask(){
          //call service layer where business logic resides
          //other autowired beans here

}
```

I have 2 doubts.

Q1) How can i make sure that CRON JOB is executed only if old instance has finished running. 
Q2) How to reload/refresh application context and reload all the beans  afresh for every `CRON JOB` call?

Comment: What do you mean old instance? Previous scheduler?

Comment: i mean suppose if i run the cron job on 7 PM Monday .Then i should not run the cron job on 7PM on Tuesday if the methods inside it are still running.i should wait it for finish

Answer (score 0):

For second point take a look at `spring-cloud-config` and client library `spring-cloud-config-client`. There is an HTTP endpoint to refresh beans

I have to create storage for any distributed operation like this, i.e. message queues, databases.

Answer (score 0):

For your Q1: suggest you to have class level boolean variable like `isRunning` like below

```
 public class scheduler {
    private boolean isRunning = false;

    @Scheduled(cron = "${my.cron.expression}")
    public void scheduleTask(){
       if(!isRunning) {
          isRunning = true;
          // executions goes here
       }
       isRunning = false;
   }
}
```

Q2: To Reload beans

```
public class scheduler {
    private boolean isRunning = false;

    @Scheduled(cron = "${my.cron.expression}")
    public void scheduleTask(){
       if(!isRunning) {
          isRunning = true;
          // executions goes here
       }
       isRunning = false;
       DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry registry = (DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry) 
       context.getBeanFactory();
       registry.destroySingleton({yourbean}) //destroys the bean object
       registry.registerSingleton({yourbeanname}, {newbeanobject}) //add to singleton beans cache
   }
}
```

Comment: `1)wil this work?
@Schedules({ 
  @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 1000), 
  @Scheduled(cron = "${my.cron.expression}")
})`

Comment: for 2nd part i am not sure that's  the best approach .basically i want to reload whole application context if  i could.I can have tens of "yourbean"

Answer (score -1):

The fixedDelay property makes sure that there is a delay of n millisecond between the finish time of an execution of a task and the start time of the next execution of the task.

```
@Schedules({ 
  @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 1000), 
  @Scheduled(cron = "${my.cron.expression}")
})
```

Comment: How is this relevant to my question?

Comment: This answers first part of your question

Comment: no it doesnt because i need to run my batch exactly at 7 PM.fixedDelay  will make it run after a specific amount of time.And there is no fixed time when my batch will finish running.SO it will run daily at different times

Comment: Read this first - The fixedDelay property makes sure that there is a delay of n millisecond between the finish time of an execution of a task and the start time of the next execution of the task.